# Script dies if a module that doesnt exist is used during sort() - DateTime::TimeZone::Local example

Tags: perl, sorting, timezone

```
use DateTime::TimeZone::Local;
use Test::More tests => 1;

my @input = (1 .. 10 );
my (@output) = sort {
    DateTime::TimeZone::Local->TimeZone();
    $a cmp $b
} @input;

is_deeply(\@output, \@input);
```

Output:

```
1..1
Can't return outside a subroutine at /usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8/DateTime/TimeZone/Local.pm line 72.
# Looks like your test exited with 9 before it could output anything.

shell returned 9
```

I have checked and it definitely is inside a sub routine. It doesn't appear to be anything to do with the module used, this code also causes the same error:

```
my @output = sort {
    sub1();
} (1 .. 5);

sub sub1 {
    eval "use ModuleDoesntExist";
    return 1; # remove this and get a seg fault
}
```

Looks like it is a bug in `perl` more than anything. Any ideas? More interested in why this is happening than a workaround - it only occurs if the module doesn't exist.

Comment: Running on linux, PERL version 5.8.8 - you? :(

Comment: Also able to replicate on perl v5.10.1, debian sid (testing)

Comment: version 0.01 

but there is a bug report saying this hasnt been updated ;) - I am running the latest cpan download. For the code, see latest post edit.

Comment: v5.10.1 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread (and DateTime::TimeZone is v1.23), no pb.

Comment: Install `Devel::Trace` and check the output of `perl -d:Trace the_program.pl`

Comment: Output from the code in the last edit.

time elapsed (wall):   0.0127
time running program:  0.0058  (45.28%)
time profiling (est.): 0.0070  (54.72%)
number of calls:       4
        0.0000   strict::import
        0.0001   <anon>:/data0/www/adcourier.broadbean/site/Devel/Trace.pm:323

Comment: Same problem on 5.10.0 on Mac OS X 10.6.5. In its simplest form, the problem can be reproduced thus: `print sort { eval "BEGIN { die }"; return $a <=> $b;} (1,0);` - it's a fascinating problem, don't know the answer yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as though it is actually a bug in Perl. See [this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/perl/porters/256807) on the Perl Porters list.

Comment: The workaround for this particular case is to do:

local $^O = "Unix";

before the sort loop so the eval never fails :)